# How do I shorten validation time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis

I have a query I'm using as the source for an OLE DB source component. When I load the package or try to execute the package, the validation on that component takes a very long time. In fact, I left the package overnight and it hadn't finished validating the next morning.

I've found so many (too many) examples of how to delay validation, work offline, etc., but I don't want to workaround the validation. I want to figure out how to make the validation process faster. Currently, when I run the query in SSMS it returns one row (total) in 20 seconds, so *why does validation currently run for many hours without completion*?

When I run `sp_who2` I see that package is executing a select statement against the db with very high `CPUTime` and low `DiskIO` (e.g. 390000/300). Is this the issue? If so, how do I correct this or where do need to go to investigate how to fix this? My package is sitting on the same server that the SQL Serve instance is running on, so I can't imagine connection issues are the cause of the validation slowness.

**UPDATE**

I'm on a tight deadline, so I will have to stop investigating the root cause of this for now. To workaround this, I replaced the Data Flow task where the OLE DB Source component was using this query with an Execute SQL task. I then created a stored procedure that simply does `INSERT INTO TableName SELECT Col1,Col2,ect. FROM ViewName`. When I run the package now it all runs in a reasonable amount of time like I would expect it to. I'm not going to make this the answer to the question because this still really bothers me, and I'm losing some built in logging functionality in SSIS to do it this way. If anyone knows the asnwer, please let me know!

Comment: What is the wait_type? You can use `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see that.

Comment: high cpu sounds like excessive (table/index) scanning of in-memory pages and/or some sort of spinlock contention; generally speaking, find the query in question, obtain the query plan, and do some basic P&T; could be something as simple as a missing index or missing statistics (even on system/catalog tables)

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I don't see any session IDs that match the SPID I see on `sp_who2`... I thought session IDs mapped to SPIDs, but maybe they don't?

Comment: They are same number. I suggest you use sp_whoisactive which shows everything in one place and lot easier.  Also there are ways to collect wait_stats for one session. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation/

Comment: @markp how would I see if it's something on a system/catalog table?

Comment: you'd have to grab a copy of the query in question to see if it references a system/catalog table; I only mentioned this as a potential issue because many system procs routinely run queries against system/catalog tables, and every once in awhile I find a db with a large volume of objects where system procs run poorly due to out-of-date stats on system/catalog tables ... ymmv; back to the original issue ... you need to run through normal P&T methods on that query to find out why it's running so long

Comment: @markp I see. The query isn't running long for what it's doing; 20 seconds is reasonable to me. What's not reasonable is how long the query takes to validate in SSIS (many hours). There seems to be some disconnect between the two, which leads me to believe that something outside of the query itself is causing the issue.

Comment: @ARich; sorry, I was actually referring to the monitoring of the validation process; NOTE: I have no idea what 'validation' encompasses but if you're seeing high cpu usage in the MSSQL then I'm assuming `validation` requires running one or more queries ... and it's that query(s) that I was referring to doing P&T on.

Comment: @markp Oh! I'm not sure how to look at the queries being executed during validation, but I'll see if I can find something online to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your OLE DB source is causing the issue

1. Create a new table with the same schema as your current source and point the component at it.
2. Within the package, update to your actual source, as this will force it to handle it at run-time.  The easiest way I have found to do this is to create a variable and assign it to the source expression.  See an example of this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288183/parameterized-oledb-source-query

Another possible solution is to set the DelayValidation property of the Data Flow task to True - See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337088(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the proposed solution appears to be another workaround...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue too, finally this solution below help:

1. Go to Extensions > SSIS > select 'Work Offline'
2. SET 'Delay Validation=TRUE' for all variable connections.
3. Right click OLE DB Source or OLE DB Destination > Show Advanced Editor > Component Tab > Validate External Data set to False
4. uncheck 'Work Offline' then run the package again